# Netbeans,maven project lombok - cannot find symbol

Tags: java

I use Netbeans 8, java 1.7.
I imported maven project. This project contains lombok.jar

In class view i have many errors , cimple errors. I can not find enable annotation processors for imported maven projec. 
Project -> properties ->Build-> compile does not contains it.

I have no ide how fix it. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 5):

You have to switch to a previous version of lombook (1.14.8 works fine) :

```
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId> 
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId> 
        <version>1.14.8</version> 
        <scope>provided</scope> 
    </dependency>
```

I had this issue when I changed my java version from 1.7 to 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error using Netbeans 8.0.2, OpenJDK 1.7 and Lombok 1.16.+. 
I changed Lombok version to 1.14.8 and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it started working after I changed Java Platform option in NetBeans from 1.7 to 1.6 (Right click on project -> Properties -> Build -> Compile).
I changed it afterwards back from 1.6 to 1.7 and it still worked properly.

Answer (score -3):

Found a solution using a Maven plugin:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.16.8.0</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>generate-sources</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>delombok</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Basically the code gets "delomboked", meaning classes are generated and put into the "generated-sources"-folder. The plugin runs every time the code is rebuilt.

For further explanation, see https://www.illucit.com/blog/2016/03/lombok-1-16-with-netbeans-8-1-maven/